# How to change text color of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Tags: java, android

I am setting adapter to listview and the text color is showing white. How can i change the text color without making my own row item layout? Below is my code which is throwing this error-

```
01-15 16:33:40.197: E/AndroidRuntime(6088): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 16:33:40.197: E/AndroidRuntime(6088):     at com.mb.pyramid.ui.fragment.DeviceListFragment$2.getView(DeviceListFragment.java:73)
```

My code :

```
mBTAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    return view;
                }
            };
```

Comment: you are using incorrect ID in `findViewById()` use `android.R.id.text1` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and you will be good `:)`

Comment: btw you can create your own layout ... It is hardly asking too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` contains only a `TextView`. In this case you can cast the return value of `super.getView(...)` avoiding the `findViewById`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
return textView;
```